# PHP and MySql to generate KML

Tags: php, mysql, kml, html-entities

I'm trying to make a dynamic KML from a PHP using this [Article](https://developers.google.com/kml/articles/phpmysqlkml), but I already have the values of my Polygons and some of them are Multiple Polygons. I decided to put this values on a Database so I just have to query them and put it on the kml, but when a try to use it it returns this:

```
&lt;Polygon&gt;&lt;extrude&gt;1&lt;/extrude&gt;     &lt;tessellate&gt;1&lt;/tessellate&gt;&lt;outerBoundaryIs&gt;&lt;LinearRing&gt;
&lt;coordinates&gt;
```

Instead of:

```
<Polygon>
<extrude>1<extrude>
<tessallete>.... etc
```

Here's how I'm trying to put this info:

```
$multiGeometryNode = $dom->createElement('MultiGeometry', htmlspecialchars($row['kml']));
```

Any ideas? By the way, if I use a echo to show htmlspecialchars($row['kml']) it works, but when I try to use it in the createElement it doesn't.

Comment: It seems as if the `<` and the `>` are being escaped. You could always try [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: actually i try to use this function that i found function keephtml($string){
          $res = htmlentities($string);
          $res = str_replace("&lt;","<",$res);
          $res = str_replace("&gt;",">",$res);
          $res = str_replace("&quot;",'"',$res);
          $res = str_replace("&amp;",'&',$res);
          return $res;
}

Comment: Try `$string = html_entity_decode($string);`

Comment: it doesn't work &lt;Polygon&gt;&lt;extrude&gt;1&lt;/extrude&gt;   &lt;tessellate&gt;1&lt;/tessellate&gt;&lt;outerBoundaryIs&gt;    &lt;LinearRing&gt;     &lt;coordinates&gt;

i think that could be something with the createElement function because if i use an echo everything works fine

Comment: When you use echo and view source, what do you see?

Comment: <Polygon><extrude>1</extrude>  <tessellate>1</tessellate><outerBoundaryIs>  <LinearRing>  <coordinates>  -116.5965100878921,31.88959120327374,0 ..... this is what im expecting to see on the kml

Comment: That is if you view source? Hmmm... what is the ouput if you call `var_dump($string);`?

Comment: string(1635) "1  1  -116.5965100878921,31.88959120327374,0 -116.5971223417851,31.89051611907432,0 ...

Comment: srry this is what it show on source with vardump
string(1635) "<Polygon><extrude>1</extrude>   <tessellate>1</tessellate><outerBoundaryIs>    <LinearRing>     <coordinates>      -116.5965100878921,31.88959120327374,0 -116.5971223417851,31.89051611907432,0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that I misread what you were doing.

Try

```
$multiGeometryNode = $dom->createElement('MultiGeometry', $row['kml']);
```

instead of

```
$multiGeometryNode = $dom->createElement('MultiGeometry', htmlspecialchars($row['kml']));
```

The [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function escapes all of the html characters. So your `<` signs were becoming `&lt;` however they were being rendered as `<` in the browser.